# Spring @RequestParam arguments not being passed in POST method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm having a problem with Spring and a post request.  I'm setting up an controller method for an Ajax call, see the method definition below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add.page", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Object createComment(
        @RequestParam(value = "uuid", required = false) String entityUuid,
        @RequestParam(value = "type", required = false) String entityType,
        @RequestParam(value = "text", required = false) String text,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
        ....
```

No matter what way I make the HTML call, the values for the `@RequestParam` parameters are always null.  I have many other methods that looks like this, the main difference is that the others are GET methods, whereas this one is a POST.  Is it not possible to use `@RequestParam` with a POST method?

I'm using Spring version 3.0.7.RELEASE - Does anyone know what the cause of the problem may be?

---

Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:"/comments/add.page",
    data:{
        uuid:"${param.uuid}",
        type:"${param.type}",
        text:text
    },
    success:function (data) {
        //
    }
});
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the Ajax code.  Something tells me I'm passing the parameters in the request body and not the request parameters as I expected :(

Comment: `@RequestParam` works with both POST and GET method (and in a transparent way). What encoding are you using? POST is always using UTF-8.

Comment: I've had problems like this before, the best way to figure out what's going on is to add an HttpServletRequest parameter to the method, put a break point, and see what's being sent.  I'm guessing you'll be able to figure out what's wrong by looking at how the data arrives to your method.

Comment: Please check the request which is sent with the browser(for example in chrom F12->Network tab)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the way I was calling the method.  My ajax code was passing all the parameters in the request body and not as request parameters, so that's why my `@RequestParam` parameters were all empty.  I changed my ajax code to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/comments/add.page?uuid=${param.uuid}&type=${param.type}",
    data: text,
    success: function (data) {
        //
    }
});
```

I also changed my controller method to take the text from the request body:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add.page", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Object createComment(
        @RequestParam(value = "uuid", required = false) String entityUuid,
        @RequestParam(value = "type", required = false) String entityType,
        @RequestBody String text,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
```

And now I'm getting the parameters as I expect.