# @RequestBody is not working when used along with params attribute in @RequestMapping annotation

Tags: java, spring-mvc

my code below works fine and reads the xml content from @RequestBody parameter

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "{clientCode}/paybycell.xml")
public ModelAndView payByCell(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestBody String xml,
        @PathVariable("clientCode") String clCode,
        @RequestParam Integer customerID)
        throws InvalidRequestXMLException, InternalException, Exception {
    info("request body=="+xml);
    getService().validateCityCodeCid(clCode, customerID);
    payByCell(xml, clCode, customerID);
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
    return null;
}
```

the log file shows the content for eg as

```
request body==<?xml version="1.0"encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PayByCell>
```

but i wanted to use the same url pattern on a different method also baesd on the request parameter,Hence i added params attribute in @RequestMapping element as shown below

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/{clientCode}/paybycell.xml", params = { "customerID", "vendorName"})
public ModelAndView payByCellMultipleVendor(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestBody String xml,
        @PathVariable("clientCode") String clCode,
        @RequestParam("customerID") Integer customerID,
        @RequestParam("vendorName") String vendorName)
        throws InvalidRequestXMLException, InternalException, Exception {
    if (vendorName == null) {
        throw new BadRequestException("Check vendorName");
    }
    info("request body=="+xml);
    getService().validateCityCodeCid(clCode, customerID);
    payByCell(xml, clCode, customerID, vendorName);
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
    return null;
}
```

but now my @RequestBody content is not read and shows empty vlue in the logs like

```
request body==
```

what is wrong.?

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14006619/106261

Comment: Can you show us the payload of your second request? How are you sending it?